# Replacement of Inputstream in java which doesn't have blocking function

Tags: java, inputstream, blocking

When I try to call `.read` method of `inputstream` with multiple parallel request,time response increases. I think it is blocked till it read previous one response.

What will be the alternative for `InputStream`  ?

i m using UNIX domain socket and from there i m trying to read data from inputstream,Here the code i m using----------

-

```
UnixDomainSocketClient socket = new UnixDomainSocketClient(sockFileName, JUDS.SOCK_STREAM);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(inputStreamData.getBytes());
String modelResponse = "";
while (true) {
            try {
                modelResponse += (char) in.read();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;

            }
        }
        out.flush();
        socket.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
}
```

Comment: Try something like [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)...

Comment: I already implemented this thing but still the same issue :(

Comment: Provide code. Or look at non-blocking IO (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html)

Comment: Hi JEY, I have attached the code.please have a look. I am using UNIX domain socket to connect Unix socket. Have tried various non-blocking IO of Java NIO was unable to fix the error.   Thanks, Raj

Comment: what library are you using gor UnixDomainSocketClient ? Check its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to call .read method of inputstream with multiple parallel request,time response increases. I think it is blocked till it read previous one response.

No. It is blocked until data arrives on *this socket.* It has nothing to do with the other sockets, except for the overall load on the machine. Reads are not sequentialized as between different input streams.

> What will be the alternative for InputStream?

Non-blocking I/O or asynchronous I/O via the NIO package, but you haven't correctly identified your problem. You may have some undue synchronization in your application. Or maybe your diagnosis is incorrect.

Comment: I have attached code above, please let me know where the synchronization is happening.If you want any other information about the application, please feel free to ask.

Comment: I only said 'appears', which I've changed to 'may', and we only have your word for it that your application is sequentializing reads on different sockets in the first place, which seems like a wrong diagnosis. Your code is appalling. It ignores end of stream. If `read()` returns -1, the peer has disconnected, and your code doesn't log `IOExceptions`. So anything could have happened, most probably a spin loop.